# vxWorks-7 jump to bootloader

Tags: u-boot, vxworks

Is there a way in vxWorks-7 to restart to the bootloader, we are using u-boot. We have a hardware issue with our current board, and would like to jump to u-boot to restart the bard instead of power cycling it.

Dennis

Comment: What makes you think that the copy of U-Boot in memory is still intact?  How are you going to guarantee that the image is intact?  Who is going to setup the C runtime environment for U-Boot?

Comment: I guess a better question is how do I jump to the reset vector?

Comment: Why not using fast boot? it will not power cycle. Just add INCLUDE_FAST_REBOOT component to the image and call reboot() function.

Answer (score 0):

A methode is maybe to use the reboot() function on console (that of course can also be used from code).
If the BSP implementation is okay, it should restart without a power-cycle.
At least that works for us -> VxWorks7 with an ARM system. But i have to say, we are not using u-boot (we are using barebox).